# javascript on error of image is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

in my rails project, users give url of online image.

­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­in some cases, image is deleted after some time.

­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­In view

```
= image_tag(media.thumbnail_url , :class => "image_test")
```

so tried to handle deleted images using Javascript
in ready method I used,

```
$('img').on("error", function () {
    var missing = "#{asset_path('missing.png')}";
    $(this).attr('src', missing);
 });
```

This is not working,
To test, If after page loaded I tried to change URL manually from browser than this show missing.png which I want to show.

I don't know what I 'm doing wrong

Comment: Is this script in a view? If not - I see you are trying to interpolate Ruby code directly into Javascript which will not work.

Comment: @msbarnard yes its in the view, no issue with ruby code.
as I said in question "If after page loaded I tried to change URL manually from browser than this show missing.png which I want to show"
Its working but not in time.